# I can’t figure out the magnetic field around a non-straight wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Say I have a circuit where the wire has a shape defined by some closed
Parametric defined as $(X(t), Y(t), Z(t))$ (it is a loop), how do I calculate the entire magnetic field around the circuit?

Comment: [Biot–Savart Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot–Savart_law#Electric_currents_(along_a_closed_curve/wire)). If you can’t evaluate the integral analytically, you can always do it numerically.

Comment: I heard that I could check a comment if it provided the info I needed, how do I do that

Comment: @GIORGIGOGIBERIDZE How to: Click the little triangle above the small flag to the left of the comment box.

Comment: @Ghoster:  You should post that as an answer so it can be accepted — the OP has indicated that it gave them the info they needed.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus:  New users need 15 rep to upvote answers and/or comments.

Comment: @GIORGIGOGIBERIDZE:  Ghoster posted the above as a "comment", not an "answer", so it can't be accepted the way you're expecting it to.  If they re-post it as an answer, then it'll appear below this comments section, and there'll be a check mark icon to the left of it that you can click on to "accept" their answer.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you @AlbertusMagnus